# FFMPEG: RTSP re-stream dies randomly

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, rtmp, flv, video-encoding

I have a security camera streaming RTSP, and I wish to re-stream this to an RTMP ingest server. For now I'm using my laptop as an ffmpeg proxy, but eventually I'll use a raspberry pi or something similar (cheap/small)

Here's the command I'm using (pretty simple):

```
ffmpeg -i rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major -c:v libx264 -c:a none -f flv rtmp://output/camera_stream
```

This works but after a minute or two the stream dies. Here's the output:

```
ffmpeg version N-90057-g7c82e0f Copyright (c) 2000-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/sbarnett/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101
  libavcodec     58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major':
  Metadata:
    title           : h264major
    comment         : h264major
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.360000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 720x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] profile High, level 3.0
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] 264 - core 155 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, flv, to 'rtmp://output/camera_stream':
  Metadata:
    title           : h264major
    comment         : h264major
    encoder         : Lavf58.9.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) ([7][0][0][0] / 0x0007), yuvj420p(pc), 720x480, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 1k tbn, 25 tbc
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.11.101 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 29 times
[rtsp @ 0x3847600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x3847600] RTP: missed 48 packets
Past duration 0.999992 too large
    Last message repeated 4 times
frame=   44 fps=0.0 q=0.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.00 bitrate=N/A dup=0 drop=5 speed=   0x    
frame=   57 fps= 54 q=28.0 size=      43kB time=00:00:00.16 bitrate=2186.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.153x    
... (lots of similar messages) ...   
frame= 1163 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1341kB time=00:00:44.84 bitrate= 245.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.99x    
frame= 1177 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1353kB time=00:00:45.40 bitrate= 244.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.99x    
[rtsp @ 0x3847600] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x3847600] RTP: missed 2 packets
frame= 1190 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1370kB time=00:00:45.92 bitrate= 244.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.99x    
[h264 @ 0x38c08c0] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
frame= 1201 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1381kB time=00:00:46.36 bitrate= 244.0kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.989x    
frame= 1214 fps= 26 q=28.0 size=    1393kB time=00:00:46.88 bitrate= 243.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.989x    
... (lots of similar messages) ...    
frame= 1761 fps= 25 q=28.0 size=    2030kB time=00:01:08.80 bitrate= 241.7kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.993x    
frame= 1774 fps= 25 q=28.0 size=    2041kB time=00:01:09.32 bitrate= 241.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=0.993x    
[flv @ 0x3884900] Failed to update header with correct duration.
[flv @ 0x3884900] Failed to update header with correct filesize.
frame= 1782 fps= 25 q=-1.0 Lsize=    2127kB time=00:01:11.64 bitrate= 243.2kbits/s dup=0 drop=5 speed=1.02x    
video:2092kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.679417%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] frame I:8     Avg QP:16.89  size: 42446
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] frame P:1672  Avg QP:19.54  size:  1065
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] frame B:102   Avg QP:23.00  size:   205
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] consecutive B-frames: 92.4%  0.0%  0.0%  7.6%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] mb I  I16..4: 12.9% 36.2% 50.9%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] mb P  I16..4:  0.2%  0.2%  0.0%  P16..4: 16.7%  0.7%  1.0%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:81.1%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 11.7%  0.1%  0.0%  direct: 1.5%  skip:86.5%  L0:62.2% L1:35.3% BI: 2.5%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] 8x8 transform intra:40.8% inter:47.4%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 46.5% 53.0% 17.2% inter: 3.9% 8.7% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] i16 v,h,dc,p: 21% 56%  8% 15%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 23% 33% 31%  1%  2%  3%  2%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 25% 39%  9%  3%  3%  4%  5%  3%  8%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] i8c dc,h,v,p: 43% 33% 21%  3%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] ref P L0: 88.0%  1.4%  6.6%  4.0%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] ref B L0: 99.4%  0.5%  0.1%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] ref B L1: 99.4%  0.6%
[libx264 @ 0x38843c0] kb/s:238.73
```

The camera is pretty cheap (from China) so it's likely I'm getting bad data from it or it's cutting out for a few seconds at a time. Ideally I would need ffmpeg to handle this well (ignore bad data, wait as long as necessary for good data to resume encoding)

Using `ffplay` to check out the RTSP stream, I get output like the following:

```
$> ffplay -i rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major
ffplay version N-90057-g7c82e0f Copyright (c) 2003-2018 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 5.4.0 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.6) 20160609
  configuration: --prefix=/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build --pkg-config-flags=--static --extra-cflags=-I/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/include --extra-ldflags=-L/home/sbarnett/ffmpeg_build/lib --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --bindir=/home/sbarnett/bin --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libspeex --enable-nonfree
  libavutil      56.  7.101 / 56.  7.101
  libavcodec     58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavformat    58.  9.100 / 58.  9.100
  libavdevice    58.  1.100 / 58.  1.100
  libavfilter     7. 12.100 /  7. 12.100
  libswscale      5.  0.101 /  5.  0.101
  libswresample   3.  0.101 /  3.  0.101
  libpostproc    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
Input #0, rtsp, from 'rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major':0B f=0/0
  Metadata:
    title           : h264major
    comment         : h264major
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.320000, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuvj420p(pc, bt709, progressive), 720x480, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
[swscaler @ 0x7f6bbc093180] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc0041080] error while decoding MB 44 28, bytestream -37
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc0041080] concealing 95 DC, 95 AC, 95 MV errors in I frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 1 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc0041080] error while decoding MB 43 29, bytestream -49
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc0041080] concealing 51 DC, 51 AC, 51 MV errors in I frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 2 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc0041080] Increasing reorder buffer to 1
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 3 packets
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc02c3600] error while decoding MB 27 29, bytestream -24
[h264 @ 0x7f6bc02c3600] concealing 67 DC, 67 AC, 67 MV errors in I frame
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 2 packets
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 42 packets
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] max delay reached. need to consume packet
[rtsp @ 0x7f6bc0000940] RTP: missed 2 packets
```

Then eventually the video just freezes. The first time it froze after around 5 minutes, but I wasn't able to say definitively if it froze the instant 44 packets were dropped or if it froze randomly later. So the second time I stared intently.... **for 21 minutes**. Then I got bored of it not freezing, turned to pet my cat, and when I looked back 15 seconds later it was frozen. I think it only breaks when no one is watching it.

What I can say definitively is:

- While running normally, `M-V` hovers **around** 0 (anywhere between `-0.01` and `+0.01`)
- Once frozen, `M-V` begins to count down into negative numbers without stopping - although at a rate slower than `-1` per second
- While running normally, `aq` is `0KB` and `vq` is a positive number (I think it was `30KB` or so?)
- Once frozen, `vq` is also `0KB`

It's a really cheap camera with a crummy power supply that goes out if you breathe on it, so it's likely the camera is going temporarily offline during this time -- but I'd like ffmpeg to wait out a timeout and resume streaming when it sees the camera again.

Comment: Check online if there's a way to set bit-rate (set it lower, find recommended settings). Also try using `Baseline` profile, instead of current `High`. Basically you're losing a lot of frames (possibly even keyframes). I would expect the picture to get "glitched" up over time but you say the stream just cuts off?

Comment: @VC.One The camera has a few options for adjusting resolution and frame rate (I can't directly affect bitrate, but I can indirectly lower it with these settings) - although I don't know if there's a way to switch the profile to baseline. I'm experiencing the stream suddenly ending, however, not getting "glitched" up over time. FFMPEG will simply stop streaming with no warning or explanation. My previous theory was that the RTSP stream is going a few second without delivering new data and FFMPEG is giving up on it - but settings a `timeout` and `stimeout` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Sorry for delay to respond. If still not fixed... Test with `ffplay -i rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major` does it play ok and longer than usual 2 minutes? Anyways to the main thing... (1) Does it work fine if you simply output to file on disk (not RTMP stream) using `-f flv testvideo.flv` ...

Comment: (2) You can set FFmpeg output preferences (bitrate and profile, etc, of the RTMP stream) using this [Streaming Guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide). For example try: `ffmpeg -i rtsp://@10.0.0.16:554/1/h264major -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -profile:v main -level:v 3.0 -b:v 90k -c:a none -f flv rtmp://output/camera_stream`

Comment: @VC.One Running `ffplay` the video went for about 5 minutes then froze suddenly. The console still seems to be moving, but the video stopped. This is in the console: `474.44 M-V:-14.744 fd=  32 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=1/1` (the first number is constantly counting up and the second number is constantly getting more negative). I also see in the console output a historical message: `RTP: missed 44 packets` - but I don't know if this happened when it froze or before. I wasn't paying that close of attention.

Comment: _"I think it only breaks when no one is watching it."_ haha. I think it's just jealous of your cat. At least it lasted 20 mins so you know the setup can work... I don't think we can call this a software issue since FFmpeg side is working fine. Your movement (with vibrations) to look at the cat could affect this power supply, is it possible?

Comment: @VC.One It's possible the movement messed with the power supply (previously it was dying when I wasn't at my desk, but the cats may have been messing with it). Is there are way to have ffmpeg wait a minute and try to re-establish the stream, though? Rather than just giving up and dying the moment data stops?

Comment: I'm not aware of any `retry` option but if you know about **std in/out** then you could use that to control FFmpeg with a programming language like Java, C#, and Python... Basically you run FFmpeg.exe via the language and then receive those console outputs into a **string** variable. If the text contains negatives lower than `-0.01` then your code will assume it's frozen and can restart the process.